# Reading JSON data from Google Geocoding API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to learn about Google Maps Geocoding and how to read the JSON data it sends back. This is what Google sends back:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I get this response with this code:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  var address = encodeURIComponent($("#location").val());

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY,
    dataType: "json",
    success: processJSON
  });

  function processJSON(json) {
    // Do stuff here
  }
});
```

The problem is I don't know what to put inside `processJSON`. I was reading the tutorial here: https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/ and the documentation on `.getJSON()` on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. However, I'm having trouble understanding both sites.

If I wanted to get the `postal_code`, how would I do read the data? I tried this:

```
function processJSON(json) {
    // Do stuff here
    alert("Postal Code:" + json.address_components[6].long_name);
  }
```

I tried it with `getJSON()` as well after `success`:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  alert("Postal Code:" + json.address_components[6].long_name);
 });
```

However, neither alert anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add success function after youu ajax

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  var address = encodeURIComponent($("#location").val());

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY,
    dataType: "json",
    success: processJSON
  }).success(function(data){
    processJSON(data);
  }

  function processJSON(json) {
    // Do stuff here
    console.log(json);
    alert("Postal Code:" + json.results[0].address_components[6].long_name);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it go into the function; however, it says `address_components` is undefined.

Comment: json.results.address_components[6].long_name

Comment: Same error but now it's on `json.results` (undefined).

Comment: you can console.log json in the processJSON function to see what it really is.

Comment: I've reedit my answer, try again, and see the console output.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll remember `console.log` next time for debugging; very useful! It was `json.results[0].address_components[6].long_name`.

Comment: yeah i modify answer.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't rely on `json.results[0].address_components[6]` being a `postal_code` at all. Instead, you should iterate trough all `json.results[]` and take the one that has `postal_code` in its `json.results[i].types`

Comment: @miguev can you please provide a working fiddle? or example on how to get value using types?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to parse the data on your success function.

```
function processJSON(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
   //..
}
```

Also add an error function to your $.ajax as well

```
$.ajax({ 
    type..
    url...
    success..
    error: function() {
        console.log('error on request')
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I get this error: `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the error function!

Comment: Try to see the result of the query using a chrome rest client plugin. There's a few in the chrome store. You might not be receiving a json.