# get zipcode from latitude and longitude in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

want to show the postal code of a location from latitude and longitude of that location. below is my code.

```
function markerLocation() { 
  var currentLocation = marker.getPosition();
  var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();        
  var location  = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.lat(), currentLocation.lng());

  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': location , function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
      var add = results[0].address_components[1][1];
      document.getElementById('lat').value = add;
    }
  });
```

Here I want to show the postal code in lat. but when i use address_components it shows undefined.
kindly help.

Comment: Where is the PHP here? Show us the `results` array contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669434/reading-json-data-from-google-geocoding-api-with-jquery this might help you.

Comment: You need to parse the result to find the address_components entry with type postal_code, it won't always be `results[0].address_components[1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="postal_code"/>
<input id="street"/>
...
```

script

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
for(var i in results[0].address_components) {
  // skip items with no types 
  if(typeof results[0].address_components[i].types == 'undefined') {
    continue;
  }

  if(results[0].address_components[i].types.indexOf('postal_code') > -1) {
    document.getElementById('postal_code').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
  }
  if(results[0].address_components[i].types.indexOf('street') > -1) {
    document.getElementById('street').value = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
  }
  ...
}
}
```